# preg_replace in PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I'm using a preg_replace function to make sure all data entered are numbers.

It looks like this:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
if( isset( $name ) ) $name = stripslashes( strip_tags( $name ) );
$name = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $name);
if (isset($name)){
if(!preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $name)){
    echo '<br>Invalid data';
} else {
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO categories(post_topic) VALUES(:name)");
$stmt->bindValue(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
}
}
```

But when the page first loads, it says invalid data already even though $name isn't set.  How would I make it so that the error message only shows up if the value has invalid characters in it?

Comment: For "1" thing, you need an opening brace for `if( isset( $name ) )` as in `if( isset( $name ) ) {`

Comment: preg_replace has nothing to do with PDO.

Comment: One too Many issetsssssssss

Comment: `preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $name)`, from that point forward `$name` is set, to an empty string. Why do you have multiple `if`'s instead of just the one around the lot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if a POST has actually occurred. Right now your code runs unconditionally:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    .... do your stuff here ...
}
```